# Nuxt 3 - Google Serach console page not rendering correct

Tags: google-search-console, nuxtjs3

I have a problem with search console. The page is not rendering (screenshot in attachment). When I click on more information I get a message (downloaded resources 23/42). Am I doing something wrong?

[image]